# Please help identifying these parts, brown and dark grey base with light brown feet

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

[image: some dusty Star Wars LEGO]

I recently got hold of a huge box of mixed LEGO Star Wars. 
Any idea which set this piece is from?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These parts are from:

[image]
[9491-1 : Geonosian Cannon](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9491-1#T=I)